# Container privileges

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I want to deploy an an app in cloudfoundry that needs to have access to a file system for storage purposes. As the appcloud only provides S3 support I wanted to use the https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse in order to make the conversion. However, this image needs to be run as "privileged" and this is not possible in a standard Cloudfoundry instance. 
According to the documentation, https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/concepts/container-security.html, there is a way to tune the privileges of a container via the diego manifest. 
Is this a possibility? is this accessible for the cloudfoundry users? Any other way I can run this container?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure the usage of privileged/unprivileged containers as a CF user. You would need to have operator level access to do that. Additionally, the operator would need to enable usage of privileged container for all app. You can't turn it on for individual apps.

See docs here:

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/container-security.html#types